# Dividing two double integers in Forth

Tags: integer-arithmetic, forth

I'm using Gforth, and I've looked for a standard Forth word for dividing two double integers, or at least a mixed division of a double integer by a single integer, yet supporting double integers as a result. There doesn't seem to be one. `SM/REM`, `FM/MOD` and `UM/MOD` have all limitations.

Did I miss anything? Why wouldn't such a word already come built-in with Forth? The operation is well-defined and no arithmetic overflows can happen. Is it necessary to program it myself?

Comment: Just short hint: you can use `DU/MOD` word in the well know [bigmath library](https://bitbucket.org/tgunr/usr/raw/master/share/SwiftForth/lib/options/bigmath.f) from SwitfForth.

Answer (score 1):

`M*/ (d n u -- result)` may be the word you're looking for. From *Starting Forth* (the original print version):

> Multiplies a 32-bit number by a 16-bit number and divides the triple-length result by a 16-bit number (d*n/u). Returns a 32-bit result. All values are signed.

So to divide a double by a single, you could subtitute *n* for *1*. [Included in DPANS94](https://forth-standard.org/standard/double/MTimesDiv), "The optional Double-Number word set".